# Scrape the feature image from this website but it returns this `data:image/gif

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Using Scrapy and Scrapy shell in python to scrape the feature image from this website https://www.thrillist.com/travel/nation/all-the-ways-to-cool-off-in-austin but it returns this `data:image/gif;base64,R0` instead of src of the image, I need the help of someone if any one tell me the way to fix this to get src of the  image

Here is my Code

```
Feature_Image = [i.strip() for i in response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/picture/img/@src').getall()][0]
```

Comment: Are you looking for **one** feature image, or are you looking for all images from that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest image on that page would be the one marked (somehow) for Desktop - common sense logic. So why not try to locate its source like below?

```
pic = response.xpath('//picture[@data-testid="picture-tag"]//source[@data-size="desktop"]/@srcset').get()
```

Result is the source for the biggest size for that page poster:

```
https://assets3.thrillist.com/v1/image/3086882/1584x1056/crop;webp=auto;jpeg_quality=60;progressive.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the tag has a data-src attribute that holds the link and some image attributes. Parsing the text and extracting the first section get's you the link.

```
>>> link = response.xpath("//div[@data-element-type='ParagraphMainImage']//img/@data-src").get().split(";")[0]
>>> link
'https://assets3.thrillist.com/v1/image/3086882/414x310/crop'
```

You can add manually add `.jpg` to the end if you want to be able to differentiate what type of image it is.  The link works with and without the extension.